# How do I upload a file to a Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to pass the resume back to the Spring MVC controller. I have created a user class that saves resume/files

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zip;
private String username;
private String password;
private int enabled;
private byte[] resume;

//getters/setters for them all
```

and the controller to take in the uploaded form from the site

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {

UserDao uDao;

@Inject
public UserController(UserDao uDao) {
    this.uDao = uDao;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String postPage(Principal principal, Map model) {

    String name = principal.getName();
    User u = uDao.getByUsername(name);

    String fName = u.getFirstName();
    String lName = u.getLastName();
    String city = u.getCity();
    String state = u.getState();
    String zip = u.getZip();
    String bc = u.getBootcampAttended();

    model.put("fName", fName);
    model.put("lName", lName);
    model.put("city", city);
    model.put("state", state);
    model.put("zip", zip);
    model.put("bc", bc);

    return "user";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal) throws IOException {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes(); // alternatively, file.getInputStream();
        // application logic

        String name = principal.getName();
        User u = uDao.getByUsername(name);
        u.setResume(bytes);
        uDao.update(u);

        return "user";
    }
    return "user";

}

}
```

I am trying to pass the resume to display as a clickable file on the jsp in the postPage method.  Here is the jsp

```
            <h1>${fName}</h1>
            <h1>${lName}</h1>
            <h1>${state}</h1>
            <h1>${city}</h1>
            <h1>${zip}</h1>
            <h1>${bc}</h1>

            <form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pick file #1:</td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="file" size="50" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Any tips on how to get the file on the Spring MVC controller. Preferably to be the value of the file input as default, instead of it saying "No File Chosen". Was thinking that maybe I could convert the file back into the MultiPartFile, like how I uploaded it, but im not sure how to pass that back to the Spring MVC controller.

Thanks!

Comment: After the user uploaded the file, on the server side store it and in the reponse send the filename and file location as session attribute. On the jsp get those values and create a hyperlink with the file name and URL to retrieve the file.

Comment: @lsivaI am saving the file in a database. Will it still work if im storing it there instead of a file directory? I dont really plan on saving the files to a file directory as the site will have alot of users.

Comment: If you are storing in the database, then you may have to write a seperate  jsp to retrive the file from database and use that jsp as the file location in the hyperlink.

Comment: You don't. That is not how the file input element works ... Just pass back the ID, create a controller which uses that id to download the file. There are more then enough answers on stackoverflow on how to do that.